# How to keep aspect ratio of a videoplayer fit to screen while resizing the window

Tags: c#, winforms, fullscreen, aspect-ratio

My app is playing a video on full screen using aforge player. While resizing the window I have to maintain it's aspect ratio. For that I have done like below. But it shows some blank area on right side of [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j8rq.jpg).Also aspect ratio of video is not seem correct. How can I resolve this?

```
 private void PlayVideo_sizeChangedeventhandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScreenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;//1536
        ScreenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;//864
        float ScreenAspectRatio = (float)ScreenWidth / (float)ScreenHeight;
        float WindowAspectRatio = (float)this.Width / (float)this.Height;//1552/840

        if (WindowAspectRatio < ScreenAspectRatio)
        {
            Player.Width = this.Width;
            Player.Height = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * ScreenAspectRatio);
        }
        else
        {
            Player.Width = Convert.ToInt32(this.Height * ScreenAspectRatio);
            Player.Height = this.Height;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: please check my edited question